# Function to calculate frequencies of the data in postgress

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, greenplum

I want to calculate mean, standard deviation, percentiles(25,50,75) for the numeric variables, frequencies for categorical variables & NULL frequencies for both categorical and numeric variables by month.Below is just the sample data.I have like 20+columns and 15k+ records.I would like to have functions to perform.

```
    Date          id  score_n  score_p  score_s  Reason 

 31-12-2016       1   0.5       6      5.0      energy_drink
 31-12-2016       4     6       3       3       soft_drink
 31-12-2016       5     3       4       2       energy_drink
```

Comment: Please check the spelling of your title: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines

Answer (score 2):

The idea is:

```
select date_trunc('month', date) as yyyymm,
       avg(score_n) as avg, stddev(score_n),
       percentile_cont(0.25) within group (order by score_n),
       percentile_cont(0.50) within group (order by score_n),
       percentile_cont(0.75) within group (order by score_n)
from t
group by date_trunc('month', date);
```

You can review the aggregation functions in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-aggregate.html).

Comment: ,Thanks..i get data every weekly and i need to perform this every week..Is there any way to write it as a function where i can send date as a parameter and it executes the above sql logic?

Comment: You need to schedule a job to do that using `cron` or some other scheduler in your environment.

Comment: can we write it in as stored function/procedure ?